# Book involving a pink companion creature that time travels

Tags: story-identification

My sister and I have very vague recollections of this chapter book, read in the 90’s - the companion creature was either a flying elephant or elephant-like, spoke very fast (dialogue may have been written without punctuation or spacing), and had a strange name.

Not much to go on, I know!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember any of the art or the cover?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for story-id questions to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 11):

The speaking very fast (with no spaces or punctuation) was what tripped my mind. The creature is a "bunjee", a mammoth-like creature with suction-cup feet, and could inflate its trunk to fly.

The creature doesn't time travel on its own, but the protagonists travel back in time to rescue their father from a prehistoric era. I don't recall if the bunjee comes back to the present with them or not  though.

The book is called "The Bunjee Venture" by Stan McMurtry.

Goodreads link: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/412535.The_Bunjee_Venture

Edited to add:
I found the name of the book by searching for "childrens novel Bunjee", since I recognised the description of a flying elephant-like creature who spoke fast (with no punctuation or spaces)

Comment: Made into an ABC Afterschool Special https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_7XPErKIag  The Bunjee sounds like Gollum on fast forward.

Answer (score 2):

Could it possibly be Clifford Simak's  *[Time is the Simplest Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_is_the_Simplest_Thing)*? The hero has paranormal powers, and belongs to an organisation that can project the human mind to other star systems. He encounters a "pinkness" which can help him travel through time, and is able to save others like himself from a pogrom.